# Sequences of randomly ordered numbers with unique neighbours

Tags: r, random

I want to create randomly ordered sequences of numbers (1 to 16) such as the following:

2   6  10   1  13  16   9   4  14   7  11  15  12   8   5   3

3  14   9   1  10   7   8  15  16  12   2  11  13   4   6   5

...

My limitation is that the neighbours of the numbers have to be unique across the sequences.
So pairings like in the following example should be avoided.

4   6   3  14  11  13  10   5  **12  16**   9   2  15   8   7   1

1  15   9  14   3   6   8   5   7   2  10  13  **12  16**   4  11

Is there any algorithm or r-code/ package to solve this?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information to specify the problem.  There are approximately 2x10^13 permutations of the integers 1 to 16.  There are 16x15/2=120 pairs of neighbours.  Every neighbour pair will be repeated many times within the full list of permutations.  Is there a limit on the number of sequences you want?  If, say, "1, 2" appears in one sequence, does that rule out "2, 1" appearing in another?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The neighbour pairs should never be repeated.
"1,2" would not rule out "2,1". I have no limit on the number of sequences.

Comment: Since you have no limit on the number of sequences required, there is no general solution: the larger the number of sequences requested, the higher the chance that a repeat will occur.  Eventually, in the limit, every possible sequence will clash with another, and so the set of valid sequences will be the empty set.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Next time, pease provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `sample`, `lag` and `lead`

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:16,16, replace=F)
x2 <- sample(1:16,16, replace=F)

prevs <- dplyr::lag(x)[-1]
nexts <- dplyr::lead(x)[-16]

prevs2<- dplyr::lag(x2)[-1]
nexts2 <- dplyr::lead(x2)[-16]

x
#>  [1]  9  4  7  1  2 14 12  3 13  5 11 10  6 15 16  8
x2
#>  [1]  9 15  5 14 16 12 13 10  2  8  6  1  4  3 11  7

any(prevs==prevs2 & nexts==nexts2)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you all for your support, the last solution of gaut worked out perferctly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use simple rejection sampling. It quickly becomes inefficient if your samples are large.

Here I show it for two samples. Adjust for more samples on your own.

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(1:20, 20, replace = FALSE)
testx <- stats::filter(x, c(100, 1), sides = 1)[-1] 
#if you sample numbers with more than two digits, 
#replace 100 with a corresponding 10^n

n <- 1
repeat {
  message( "try ", n)
  n <- n + 1
  y <- sample(1:20, 20, replace = FALSE)
  testy <- stats::filter(y, c(100, 1), sides = 1)[-1]
  if (all(outer(testx, testy, "-") != 0)) break
}
# try 1
# try 2
# try 3
# try 4
# try 5
# try 6
# try 7
x
#[1] 17  5  1 10  4  2 20 18  8  7 16  9 19  6 14 15 12  3 13 11
y
#[1] 17 18  2  6 20 16 15  4 12 19 10  7 13 14  8 11  1  9  5  3
```